# Spark Unnesting Nested Schema from DynamoDB Json

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am dealing with with DynamoDB JSON that is similar to this:

```
{ 
  "name" : {"S" : "John"},
  "birthday": {
    "M" : {
       "month" : {"N": 1},
       "year" : {"N": 2000},
       "day" : {"N": 2} 
    }
  }
}
```

When I read this in spark

```
val df = spark.read.json("s3://path")
```

I get a complicated schema:

```
name : structType ( S : String),
birthday: structType (
  M : StructType (
    month : structType (N : int),
    year : structType (N : int),
    day : structType (N : int),
  )
)
```

Instead, I want to change the schema to something like

```
name : String
birthday : structType (
  month : int
  year : int
  day : int
)
```

Is there a way to do this?

My schema is in fact much larger than this example, with many deeply nested structs. I wonder also if there is dynamic way of "normalizing" the schema.

Comment: spark version ??

Comment: @Srinivas Spark 2.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use `named_struct` function:

```
df.selectExpr("""
named_struct (
  'name', name.S,
  'birthday', named_struct(
    'month', birthday.M.month.N as decimal,
    'year', birthday.M.year.N as decimal,
    'day', birthday.M.day.N as decimal,
  )
) as items
""")
```

This worked out well for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
.selectExpr("name", "birthday.M as birthday")
```

Or you could even flatten this totally up to the root level

```
.selectExpr("name", "birthday.M.*")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Dave. But won't that just make bring up the birthday field up, but will not fix the "N" that appears inside it?

Comment: Ahh I didn't see that part of the schema.  If you had a ton of fields you could do something with .schema().  if it were just these known fields you can alias each one